# asynchronous read write with device file

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am writing some binary data to a device fie like /dev/itun.

```
void ahaConnector::asyncWriteData(vector<uint8_t> packedMessage) {

    cout<<"\n async write data packed message";
    deviceStreamDescriptor.assign(device);
    boost::asio::write (
                       deviceStreamDescriptor,
                       boost::asio::buffer(packedMessage)
                       );


    readbuffer.resize(1024);
    deviceStreamDescriptor.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(readbuffer),
                                boost::bind(&ahaConnector::readHeader, this,
                                boost::asio::placeholders::error(),
                                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred()
                                ));
    io_service.run();

}

void ahaConnector::readHeader(const boost::system::error_code &ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {


    if(!ec) {

        std::cout<<"\n Bytes transfereed :"<<bytes_transferred<<" "<<readbuffer.size();


        deviceStreamDescriptor.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(readbuffer),
                                        boost::bind(&ahaConnector::readHeader, this,
                                        boost::asio::placeholders::error(),
                                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred()
                                        ));

        Callbacks callbacks;
        callbacks.OnReceivingPackedMessage();
        io_service.run();

    }
    else {

        cout<<"\n System Error Code "<<ec;
    }

}
```

The callback function readhandler is getting executed successfully, however I am not able to transfer the control from my Callback function to another class.

Is something wrong from the design perspective. I need to handle the message received from the callback function for further logic. Should I use another thread here ?

Comment: Throwing away the return value of `read` is not smart. What if you only read one byte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this code you might just want to replace the `read(device,...)` by boost Asio's support for Posix streams:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/posix/stream_descriptor.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <iostream>

static int device = 0;

using namespace boost;

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service io_svc;
    boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor iodevice(io_svc, device);

    char buffer[1024];
    function<void(system::error_code const&, size_t)> callback;
    callback = [&](boost::system::error_code const& ec, size_t bytes_transferred) {
            if (ec)
            {
                std::cout << "Error '" << ec.message() << "' during asynchronous operation\n";
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Read exactly " << bytes_transferred << " bytes\n";
                std::cout << "Data: '"; 
                std::cout.write(buffer, bytes_transferred);  
                std::cout << "'\n";

                iodevice.async_read_some(asio::buffer(buffer), callback);
            }
        };

    iodevice.async_read_some(asio::buffer(buffer), callback);

    io_svc.run();
}
```

See it **[<strike>Live On</strike> Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e2c484491b7c982)**.

Sadly on Coliru it can't work because input is redirected from a non-stream. But if you run it interactively it will work and print the first 10 characters entered.

Comment: thanks a ton for ur support, but i d love a more generic solution, please ignore the logic in my function 10 byte header. I would like to get a call back whenever there is a new packet of Message in the device file /dev/itun

Comment: @MarshelAbraham well, that's splendid. Did you just say I didn't answer your question because you changed it? You're gonna have a hard time getting help this way. People will soon not bother anymore. You're free to file a new question. I certainly don't feel tempted to answer it, seeing as it took you three days to not appreciate my answer. Note: of course, you can do the call back style using ASIO. It's a relatively straightforward change.

Comment: sorry i checked ur answer now only, i dint get time to verify it. also its a lil ahrd for me to understand boost asio concepts , I appreciate ur help, ill accept answer once I m in a position to understand ur solution . Please give me some time. thanks  a lot

Comment: @MarshelAbraham I've updated the sample with a continuous read loop and callbacks on ready data. See it **[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eec9ba7f6578eef4)** echoing input piped to stdin.

Comment: i can see that ure making an async_read_some inside the callback, can i do without it..? does that make the function recursive..will it finish reading only if the device file is empty..?

Comment: No, chaining actors does not make them recursive. Remember that async operations are... asynchronous. They return immediately. This is the essence of the actor pattern. As written my sample reads until it fails, not necessarily end of steam. But obviously you can write whatever logic you desire. Just use some kind of condition...

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on exactly what are the properties of the device. Check the documentation for the device driver you're trying to use. If the device supports non-blocking I/O, open the device with `O_NONBLOCK`, and use poll() to wait for device to be available for reading or writing.

If the device does not support non-blocking I/O, the only viable option would be to use a separate thread to read and/or write to the device, and use the background thread to construct facade that pretends and behaves like a non/blocking data source and sink.